# Missing package.json but its in current working directory

Tags: npm

I run npm install and it complains that package.json doesn't exist in the current working directory. However, it is actually present.

```
myapp$ pwd
/code/myapp

myapp$ npm --version
5.8.0
myapp$ nvm --version
0.33.5
myapp$ pip --version
pip 10.0.0 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
myapp$ node --version
v8.11.1

myapp$ ls package.json
package.json

myapp$ npm install
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: <REDACTED>.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2018-04-18T23_14_42_398Z-debug.log
```

I am drawing blanks here. I would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Looks like the REDACTED stuff has an error message which says npm is unable to find package.json from a different git repo which is referenced in the packaje.json in /code/myapp. 

I dont think this is a generic npm issue. I apologize for the spam. I wish I could close out this question.

Comment: The error means that a package you depend on hasn't have a `package.json` in their repo.